# Javafx Tableview How To Color Cells with Specific Value

Tags: css, tableview, javafx-8, uitableview, tablecell

Is there a way to color only some cells with a specific value of a `TableView`?

```
Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> historyTableCellFactory
    = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
        public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
            TableCell newCell = new TableCell<CustomerHistoryStructure, String>() {
                private Text newText;

                @Override
                public void updateItem(String items, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(items, empty);

                    if (!isEmpty()) {
                        newText = new Text(items.toString());
                        newText.setWrappingWidth(140);
                        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#e50000 ;");
                        setGraphic(newText);
                    }
                }

                private String getString() {
                    return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
                }
            };
            return newCell;
        }
    };
```

The problem with the above code is that when the program is running and I scroll on the `TableView`, other cells get colored on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with that code is that you never undo the changes done when the item is added. You never remove the `graphic`, even if the cell becomes empty and you never check for a specific value. Furthermore `items.toString()` could lead to a NPE, if you add `null` items. Also recreating the `Text` element is unnecessary. Also you never compare the item to a specific value.

```
final String specificValue = ...

new TableCell<CustomerHistoryStructure, String>() {
    private final Text newText;

    {
         newText = new Text();
         newText.setWrappingWidth(140);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            newText.setText(getString());
            setGraphic(newText);

            // adjust style depending on equality of item and specificValue
            setStyle(Objects.equals(item, specificValue) ? "-fx-background-color:#e50000 ;" : "");
        }
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you very much.. i was trying to solve it for more than 2 weeks