# Javafx TableView Color Cells with a value using CSS

Tags: css, javafx, tableview

Is there a way to color only the cells of a tableview with a value by just using css?

Comment: I doubt this is possible using pure CSS. What's the problem with having a backing Java code?

Comment: can you answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182782/javafx-tableview-how-to-color-cells-with-specific-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cell`s that just contain *any* value (i.e. `Cell`s that are non-empty) can be selected using the `filled` pseudoclass, e.g. using the following stylesheet:

```css
.table-cell:filled {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.table-row-cell:selected>.table-cell:filled,
.table-cell:selected:filled {
    -fx-background-color: purple;
}
```

However you cannot style a `Cell` containing a **specific** value using CSS alone.

Comment: ok how can i do it using java? please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182782/javafx-tableview-how-to-color-cells-with-specific-value